# seek for an useful and free utility to clean my OSX

Tags: caching, itunes, disk

Recently, I run out of my disk. Core dump in /cores occupied most space in my OSX. After clean it, I save much space. But I don't feel like to delete them manually each time,running commands in terminal. Is there an free tool to help me out.

I also found some app occupy too much cache or unnecessary files such as iTune. I also need an easy way to clean them out.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App store has so many FREE app to help you clean unnecessary files.

I recommend you FREE APP "Dr.Clean" which is developed by Trend Micro.

[Here is the link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dr.cleaner-clean-disk-optimize/id921458519?mt=12)